# how does Optuna execute the objective function?

Tags: hyperparameter-tuning

how does Optuna execute the objective function when calling study.optimize(objective, n_trials=10,
is it, for each trial ===> call the function ??, if this is the case, this means we shouldn't allow static variables inside the function, like reading data for example, am i right?